# resolve my ip with dig returns empty string

Tags: debian, dns, dig

When trying to resolve my public IP address I get an ampty string

```
ip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
```

Comment: Do you have a private range IP ?

Comment: You could try some other ways, e. g. `curl ipinfo.io/ip` or use another resolver with dig: `dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}'`

Comment: @metallic how to get IPv4?

Comment: Just add -4: `dig -4 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | awk -F'"' '{ print $2}'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason opendns is also not working for me at work. e.g. your command is not at fault, it is simply that opendns is not answering to that specific query to find the public IP address in some settings.

Google also delivers a similar service for finding out which public IP address you are using. Do:

```
ip=$(dig TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com)
```

As IPv6 takes precedence when present, for forcing an IPv4 answer, do:

```
ip=$(dig -4 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com)
```

Comment: how to get IPv4? :)

Comment: it returns `"2a01:4f8:140:43a1::2"`

Comment: Dig -4, having lunch, will come back to you later on

Comment: @GAD3R I would swear it is not a firewall matter. I am working in a big ISP, so no comms/firewall problems, and that line of opendns that used to work is not working in two different Linux systems. Google works fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add, `-4`, to your original answer like this `dig -4 +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)`. You'll get the IPv4 output that you expect.

I had the same issue with my AWS lightsail instance and this solved the problem for me.

Comment: I had the same issue with my AWS lightsail instance and this solved the problem for me.

Comment: [Edit] and add additional info in the answer, not in the comments please.